# Need help configuring visual studio for a java program

Tags: java, visual-studio-2015, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile a simple java program, and I am new to visual studio. According to the procedures I am following here is the compile.bat that I need:

```
del Output /S /Q
mkdir Output
javac *.java -d Output
cd Output
start java MyApplication
```

Here is how I configured javac as an external tool:

[image: Screen Capture]

Here is the java code:

```
import java.io.*;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
C:\>mkdir Output 
A subdirectory or file Output already exists.

C:\>javac *.java -d Output 
javac: file not found: *.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

C:\>cd Output 

C:\Output>start java MyApplication
```

As you can see, VS does not start from the project directory rather from C::-( Why? How can I fix it?

[Here](http://improve.dk/compiling-java-in-visual-studio/) Are the procedures I followed.

I do not know how; but it actually seems to work at least partially. Here is the project directory for my MinGw project:

```
C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb\mingw64\java>ls
HelloWorld.class  HelloWorld.h  HelloWorld.java  ctest.c  ctest.dll

C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb\mingw64\java>java HelloWorld
Enter a number:
2
Hello from C!
```

In another window, I looked for java process and tried to attach to it. This time ( and I tried a bunch of times before ) it seems to work:

```
C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb\mingw64\java>tasklist | findstr java
java.exe                     10660 Console                    1     19,384 K

C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb\mingw64\java>gdb -p 10660
GNU gdb (rubenvb-4.8.0) 7.5.91.20130322-cvs
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<mingw-w64-public@lists.sourceforge.net>.
Attaching to process 10660
[New Thread 10660.0x2930]
[New Thread 10660.0x273c]
[New Thread 10660.0x25b4]
[New Thread 10660.0x1624]
[New Thread 10660.0x16e4]
[New Thread 10660.0x2788]
[New Thread 10660.0x254c]
[New Thread 10660.0x2984]
[New Thread 10660.0x1c7c]
[New Thread 10660.0x154]
[New Thread 10660.0x119c]
[New Thread 10660.0x1668]
[New Thread 10660.0x23b0]
[New Thread 10660.0x13e8]
[New Thread 10660.0xfc8]
[New Thread 10660.0xe88]
[New Thread 10660.0x22dc]
Reading symbols from C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) n
Program not restarted.
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function ntdll!DbgBreakPoint,
which has no line number information.
0x00007ffb6e409031 in ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
(gdb) n
Single stepping until exit from function ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin,
which has no line number information.
[Inferior 1 (process 10660) exited normally]
(gdb) n2
Undefined command: "n2".  Try "help".
(gdb)
```

Let me know please if you see anything weird. I am gonna try to run it a number of times and see if I can follow what is going on. I have not for instance, seen so many new threads when you first run GDB. I found one more thing. I know I need to used -g option to create debugging symbols. I thought I did that, but I did not delete the previous file. I am gonna give that a try. Can someone validate that this may have caused the message GDB gives now about the debug symbols?

Comment: Why Visual Studio? Use an actual Java IDE, [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows) even has a free "Community Edition." And for "I'm building things using `javac`" that's more than enough IDE.

Comment: @nosbor - no it doesn't, `javac` runs fine, it can't find the source files.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was using MinGw to create a JNI project, and was able to compile and run it. But GDB for some reason does not attach to the running java process. I posted here about it, but got no reply. So I found online procedures for doing this with VS. That is why I am using it. On a different note; JAVA_HOME environment variable is configured correctly. I would be glad to post a session output. If you know of any other IDE that I can debug JNI projects, I would gladly give it a try. As far as IntelliJ IDEA; I believe Andorid Studio is based on it, and I was not able to debug

Comment: @millimoose Yeah, right.

Comment: I ran out of space in last comment; I did create a JNI project using Android Studio. But no one seems to know how to debug a JNI project with it. Java Native Interface projects in Android Studio work; I have even pushed the app to my phone and tested it, but I have not been able to find a way to debug it. Any ideas?

Comment: That said this would make things a bit of an X-Y problem, seems what you're really trying to accomplish is debug JNI code running in a Java process, so it's odd to have a question that does not in fact mention JNI. It's not like Visual Studio can do anything else than run java.exe, it's not going to debug Java code directly, much less debug Java AND JNI.

Comment: @millimoose. I know the tools you mentioned. Just so I am clear; you are saying compile the C code only with VS; put the complied JAVA code in the same directory, and then try to debug the project with VS? I know JNI is convoluted, but I am so close.

Comment: Here is the link for what I am running into with GDB; just in case you see something I am doing wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37375606/mingw-64-gdb-can-not-attach-to-process-on-windows-10 Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what instructions you're following here. But basically, the steps you should need are: 1. Build a JNI DLL. 2. Build a Java project that uses that DLL. 3. Run that project using `java` which should load said DLL. 4. Debug this `java.exe` process using whatever. So it's strange that you're asking for essentially a way to automate step 2 here using an external tool without having done step 1. Steps 1 and 4 are what Visual Studio is going to be most useful for, so you should focus on those if you haven't solved them, and do steps 2 and 3 in the command line by hand in the meantime.

Comment: I looked at your other question but it still doesn't mention what process it is that you're trying to attach to using `gdb`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112627/discussion-between-user3326293-and-millimoose).